# How to have two input fields next to each other in a table cell, each being 50% wide?

Tags: html, css

I have this `table`:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="half"/>
      <input type="text" class="half" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.half {
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
}
```

How can I have two `input` fields next to each other each filling up 50% of the table cell's (natural / normal) width?

Right now, this doesn't work. The table cells containing the input fields of class `half` are far too wide and I can't see why this happens.

Comment: try: .half {
   float: left;
   width: 46.5%;
}

Comment: The reason is because the input fields have a border which adds to the width of the box model. Such that `TD` width is less than the total width of `input1 border width` + `input1 width` + `input2 border width` + `input2 width`. Using `nowrap` you can get close but if you add borders you can see the overlap clearly: http://jsbin.com/wejime/2/edit - play with the input borders.

Answer (score 1):

You need two things: **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eztwh)**

1. avoid the white-space in between inline-block element *(you may then drop the float property)*.
2. include border size into width.

First, the easiest way is to remove white-space from html code and write it so :

```
  <input ... /><input  ... />
```

Second, is to switch to another box-model so :

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

Add vendor-prefix whenever needed .

Comment: +1 However, since the inputs are floated, white-space is not the case.

Comment: @HashemQolami I commented the demo where float is not needed if you mind this white-space . it is extra info if he did not know about this behavior :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't check the demo :) Thanks for editing the answer.

Comment: @GCyrillus: Thanks. This looked promising to me, so I tried it. But actually removing the white space and adding `box-sizing:border-box;` doesn't make much of a difference. The columns containing the two input fields are still unusually wide. Wider than they were when there was only one input field in them. How can this be fixed?

Comment: @Tintin81 if add : table-layout:fixed; to table , it will not allow table to grow more than 100% width (as you setted) and it should evenly size the 3 cols if no width are given. if col have a width, it will be applied.. do you have an example in mind to show ? demo updated : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eztwh

Answer (score 0):

How about applying `.half` to the `<td>` parent?

```
<td class="half">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
<table border="2px">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class= "half"/>
      <input type="text" class= "half"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

.css

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;

}
td{
padding-left: 5px;

}

.half {
   float: left;
   width: 49%;
   margin: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to resolve this, wrap then inputs in a span tag. Set the span to inline-block 50%, and the inputs to 100%. Using a box model maintains the inputs in the td

```
   http://jsfiddle.net/HgxFf/
 <table>
 <tr>
    <td>
        <span><input type="text" class="half"/></span>
        <span><input type="text" class="half" /></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text"/><input type="text"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span><input type="text"/></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td{border:1px solid #000000;font-size:0px; }

span{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    padding:0px
}

.half {
   width: 100%;
}

input[type="text"]{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
}
```